# Where can I ask a question about finding a web site for planimetry measurement?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've tried to ask about it on geographics information systems, but I was signed as off topic. 
My question is about finding and evaluating web applications related to civil cad, in particular for house planimetry import and measurement.

Comment: For readers: [The question in question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/101586). It was closed as off topic for a custom reason: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic here, but can be asked on Super User." (The question may not be totally on topic for SU.)

Comment: I'd go take a look to see if your question would be on-topic at [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

In general, questions that are a search request or asking for a product recommendation are off-topic almost everywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

The basic principle behind search requests is that we're here to provide our expertise, not help you find that expertise somewhere else.

Product recommendation questions are off-topic because they are highly-opinionated and attract spam answers.